# Javascript:Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working UI where in I want to different updatable iframes/regions. There would be 3 regions on below the other. The top being the User Search Region. As soon as a User is searched and locked the below regions should be populated by AJAX. Each region should be individually submittable. When the individual region is clicked then it should enlarge and the fields should be available for editing. Is Angular JS an appropriaet JS framework to implement this?

Comment: What have you *tried*. It's off-topic on Stack Overflow to ask if a tool is appropriate / what tools might be, because it's subjective.

Comment: I have done the same thing in plain javascript which has got issues. SO i thought why not use some Javascript frameworks which are available. Was not able to decide which framework would suit the requirement with minimum amount of coding.Not sure how its off topic on Stackoverflow as I have seen many such questions before.

Comment: I had stated my requirements clearly and also mentioned the tools which would be appropriate to implement the requirements so that people with the necessary expertise of the said tools could tell me whether it would be easy enough to do it in these tools. I am looking for a opinion which is based on expertise of the said tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exactly use the power of angularjs. Custom directives is your friend here to update the iframes.

Here is a code snippet

```
.directive('myFrame',function(){
   return {
    link:function(scope,ele,attrs){
        ele.load(function(){
            scope.$apply(attrs.myFrame);
        });
      }
   };
});
```

I am not sure if cross-domain is working..